# What is this js syntax called

Tags: javascript

I recently found JavaScript code like this:

`someFunction()()`

Function immediately invoked right after function without classic IIFE syntax.

What is that kind of syntax called? And how it works?

Comment: the function returns a function

Comment: There's no particular name; you're calling a function, that returns a function, then you call *that* function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i would say that "currying" is the right term for that

Comment: @JonasW. you would be wrong!

Answer (score 5):

Its a function that returns another function.

Here is an example on how it works, this can help you to understand better.

```
function sum(x){
  return function(y){
    return x+y;
  }
}
sum(3)(5); //8
```

Answer (score 1):

For you code to work:

```
someFunction()();
```

You need to have code that looks like this:

```js
function someFunction() {
  console.log('someFunction()');
  // do something before return
  return function() {
    console.log('someFunction()()');
    // do something else here
  }
}

someFunction()();
```

In this example you first call `someFunction` then you call the function that was returned by `someFunction`.

This can be good to do when you need to pass in a variable that will be used in the inner function but the inner function will be called in the future like this:

```js
function someFunction(outerVal) {
  console.log('Outer called.');
  return function(innerVal) {
    console.log('inner called.');
    return outerVal * innerVal;
  }
}

var inner = someFunction(12);

setTimeout(()=> {
  console.log(inner(4));
}, 1000);
```

I use this often in Node.js for common middle-ware that needs a single value to be unique.

```js
app.get('/dogs', myFn('woof'));
app.get('/cats', myFn('meow'));
app.get('/birds', myFn('tweet'));

function myFn(word) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    res.write(word).end();
  }
}
```

That is an over simplification, but can be vary powerful.